# Redirect ip to another page

Tags: networking, router, tcp

i have a modem Dlink DSL-2730U
i want to make this modem redirect some ip to another page or to another ip example : 
i have this ip :

> 123.456.7.9

i want to redirect it to

> 8.8.8.8

from the modem administration 
so can i do it ?

Comment: Why? Do you want to do this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: no problem it's just something i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw, it is a consumer electronics, with a typical web interface. As long as you stick to this, the answer is very probably: No you cannot do that.

You would have to read the IP destination address of every packet, check if it fits and change it accordingly. For that you need to define your own firewall rules (e.g. [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html)).

You could check wether [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) supports this device and try to flash the device.